# asp.net: IE 7 & 8 closes automatically (not trusted site)

Tags: asp.net, trusted-sites

in my asp.net application I'm calling a site, which is producing a .pdf file of the content of the viewed page.

In IE 9 everything is fine - the browser opens a new window and there the pdf file which has been created can be opened or saved.

In IE 7 and 8 the window opens, but after a second the window closes automatically and the result is, that the pdf file cannot be viewed.

*This occurs only in secure internet (with `https`), not intranet.*

If I add my site to "trusted sites" in the IE properties, then everything works fine.
Can i manage this problem with some code?
(I cannot simply tell my users to add the page to trusted sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read about 10-20 threads with the same problem as I had.
Most answers are to try something like "Cache-Control: private", to clear the headers correctly, to end the response correctly, to set the "Content-Type" to "application/download" or "application/octet-stream" and other Response.ApendHeader configurations.

The solution of my problem was, that I've created the link to the pdf-generating site with javascript. I changed it to a asp.net redirection and now it is working!

```
<asp:Button id="myButton" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/myPDFcreatingSite.aspx" Text="Create PDF"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to run fiddler or firebugs or whatever to capture your response header.

My guess is this is an issue with IE and how it handles expiration headers.

[Check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038707/cant-display-pdf-from-https-in-ie-8-on-64-bit-vista)

Here is a similar (if not the exact same) issue I had myself.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348214/ie-8-and-client-side-caching)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, led me in the right direction