# JavaScript not working properly on IE

Tags: javascript, popup

I am using a onclick event on my page.The functionality is to open a new page which should have the staments on that particular dated PDF when clicked on it.

`<h:link onclick="pushPost(#{statement.id});return false;">` 
and am using java script to call the onclick event which is working perfeclty in mozilla but a blank page is appearing on IE

```
function pushPost(stmtNo){
    push = window.open("StatementContent.xhtml?statement="+stmtNo, "push", 
            "directories=0,height=900,width=850,top=20,left=20,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no");
    push.focus();
}
```

Comment: What IE version is being used?  There are issues with IE8 and below with static content files.  The cache-control headers on the page that returns the .PDF more then likely need modified.  I would say there is no problems with the code above but more likely a change will need made on StatementContent.xhtml

Comment: firstly thanks for the reply.currenlty we are using IE8,so cache-control headers on the page that returns.PDF need to be modified on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348214/ie-8-and-client-side-caching).  I fought this same problem as you did, however it was a .aspx file not an .xhtml file.  You will need to take the same considerations with the HTTP cache-control headers.  If you look at it from that perspective it should solve your problem.